# Should I hide my firebase cloud function in an environment variable on the client side?

Tags: firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a React+Redux app, and using some firebase cloud functions which I call in an action creator. I was wondering, if I should save the cloud function url as an environment variable, since this code is on the client side? I already have cors implemented to only allow requestsfrom my domain.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should always make sure that endpoints that can be called from a client are robust enough to be secure if publicly disclosed. Browser, Android, and iOS apps can all be inspected and disassembled to discover outgoing request URLs.

"Security through obscurity" can buy you time, but is not in and of itself a real means of protecting your application. Instead, you should make sure that the endpoint requires sufficient authorization (e.g. by using the Firebase ID token as per [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api)).

In other words, there's no need to hide it because at the end of the day, you can't!

Comment: Thank you very much for your wisdom Michael! this was very helpful!